# Cakephp 3.0 Issue in validation when we use different validation set

Tags: validation, cakephp-3.0

I have a custom form for Change Password functionality. But the validations are not properly working on this page.

The template file (**change_password.ctp**) is:

```
<div class="users index large-9 medium-8 columns content">
    <?= $this->Form->create('change_password') ?>
    <fieldset> 
        <legend><?= __('Change password') ?></legend> 
        <?= $this->Form->input('old_password', ['type' => 'password', 'label' => 'Old password']) ?>
        <?= $this->Form->input('new_password', ['type' => 'password', 'label' => 'Password']) ?> 
        <?= $this->Form->input('confirm_password', ['type' => 'password', 'label' => 'Repeat password']) ?> 
    </fieldset> 
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Change')) ?> 
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

The validation code included in a custom function in **UsersTable.php** page:

```
public function validationChangePassword(Validator $validator) {
            $validator
                    ->requirePresence('old_password', 'create')
                    ->notEmpty('old_password');

            $validator
                    ->requirePresence('new_password', 'create')
                    ->notEmpty('new_password');

            $validator
                    ->notEmpty('confirm_password')
                    ->add('confirm_password', 'no-misspelling', [
                        'rule' => ['compareWith', 'new_password'],
                        'message' => 'Passwords are not equal',
            ]);

            return $validator;
        }
```

I included the changePassword() action in the controller **UsersController.php**

```
public function changePassword() {

        $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
        if (isset($this->request->data) && !empty($this->request->data)) {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data, [
                'validate' => 'changePassword'
            ]);
            if ($user->errors()) {


                $this->Flash->success(__('Error'));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does "not properly working" mean? Describe what is your problem.

Comment: Could you please explain how can we create validations for a custom change password form? I created a user controller and an action named changepassword and added the validation code in UsersTable.php page. The control is going to the validation function, but the validation is not working for me

Comment: Could you please correct the above code so that I can display the validation on my template page itself?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use a [different validation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/validation.html#using-a-different-validation-set) set for specific CRUD in your app?

Comment: Exactly. But I think the control goes to the validation function, but the validation is not displaying under different fields in the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your action as below:

```
public function changePassword() {

        $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
        if (isset($this->request->data) && !empty($this->request->data)) {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data, [
                'validate' => 'changePassword'
            ]);
            if ($user->errors()) {


                $this->Flash->success(__('Error'));
            }
        }
        $this->set(compact('user'));
    }
```